# How to run multiple julia files parallel?

Tags: julia

I have a pretty simple question but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. I want to run two .jl files parallel using the Julia Terminal.
I tried include("file1.jl" & "file2.jl") and include("file1.jl") & include("file2.jl") but this doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to run two different programs parallel on different cores of my cpu

Comment: is there a compelling reason to run it from the Julia REPL? can you simply run it from the command line?

Comment: Yeah I guess that would work too. In the command line I can just combine them with a "&"?

Comment: yes, if you schedule them correctly. see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do but if you wanted to run these two files on two different workers from the julia terminal you could for e.g.

```
addprocs(1) # add a worker
pmap(include,["file1.jl", "file2.jl"]) # apply include to each element 
                                       # of the array in parallel
```

But I'm pretty sure there will be a better way of doing whatever you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the responds. What is a worker in this context?

Comment: I tried your solution. The problem is the two programs don't run parallel on the different workers but one after the other.

Comment: That's because `addprocs(1)` adds 1 worker only try adding 2 workers.

Comment: But it looks like it would be more sensible for what you want to do to just run them both from the cmd line?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Yeah I guess the command line is probably simpler. I didn't know that was possible too.

Answer (score 1):

While you can probably wrangle your code into the Julia parallel computing paradigms, it seems like the simplest solution is to execute your Julia scripts from the command line. Here I assume that you are comfortable allowing your CPU to handle the task scheduling, which may or may not result in parallel execution.

What follows below is a skeleton pipeline to get you started. Replace `task.jl` with your `file1.jl`, `file2.jl`, etc.

**task.jl**

```
println("running like a cheetah")
```

**run_script.sh**

```
echo `date`
julia task.jl
julia task.jl
echo `date`
```

**run_script_parallel.sh**

```
echo `date`
julia task.jl &
julia task.jl &
wait # do not return before background tasks are complete
echo `date`
```

From the command line, ensure that your BASH scripts are executable:

```
chmod +rwx run_script.sh run_script_parallel.sh
```

Try running the scripts now. Note that my example Julia script `task.jl` returns almost immediately, so this particular comparison is a little silly:

```
./run_script.sh
./run_script_parallel.sh
```

**My output**

```
Thu Jan 5 14:24:57 PST 2017
running like a cheetah
running like a cheetah
Thu Jan 5 14:24:57 PST 2017

Thu Jan 5 14:25:05 PST 2017
running like a cheetahrunning like a cheetah

Thu Jan 5 14:25:06 PST 2017
```

The first output orders the print statements in a clean serial order. But observe in the second case that the text is running together. That is common behavior for parallel print statements.